# Functor and foldable instances for the Stream data type

Tags: haskell

I have had problems trying to implement Chris Penner's code here https://github.com/ChrisPenner/comonads-by-example/blob/master/docs/rendered/01-streams.pdf.

Specifically, in the following piece of code:

```
data Stream a = a :> Stream a
     deriving (Functor, Foldable)

{-instance Functor Stream where                                          
     f(x:>xs) = (f x):>(fmap f xs) -}

fromlist :: [a] -> Stream a
fromlist xs = go (cycle xs)
   where
     go (a: rest)= a :> go rest

countStream :: Stream Int
countStream = fromlist [0..]
```

this produces the following errors:

```
comonads.hs:17:16: error:
   • Can't make a derived instance of ‘Functor Stream’:
       You need DeriveFunctor to derive an instance for this class
   • In the data declaration for ‘Stream’
  |
17 |      deriving (Functor, Foldable)
  |                ^^^^^^^

comonads.hs:17:25: error:
   • Can't make a derived instance of ‘Foldable Stream’:
       You need DeriveFoldable to derive an instance for this class
   • In the data declaration for ‘Stream’
  |
17 |      deriving (Functor, Foldable)
```

I tried to write an instance declaration for the Stream data type (thinking this would avoid the problem), but this doesn't work, either. How can I solve my problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default Haskell can not generate the instances of a `Foldable` and `Functor`. In [*Chapter 11. Specification of Derived Instances* of the Haskell 2010 Report](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch11.html#x18-18200011) it is specified that it can automatically derive an instance of a typeclass *C* given:

> 1. *C* is one of `Eq`, `Ord`, `Enum`, `Bounded`, `Show`, or `Read`.
>
> (…)

You can make use of the [**`DeriveFoldable`**](https://downloads.haskell.org/%7Eghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#extension-DeriveFoldable) and [**`DeriveFunctor`**](https://downloads.haskell.org/%7Eghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#extension-DeriveFunctor) language extensions of the *Glasgow Haskell Compiler (GHC)* to enable this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFoldable, DeriveFunctor #-}

data Stream a = a :> Stream a
     deriving (Functor, Foldable)

fromlist :: [a] -> Stream a
fromlist xs = go (cycle xs)
   where go (a: rest) = a :> go rest

countStream :: Stream Int
countStream = fromList [0..]
```

or you can specify the instance yourself, for example:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFoldable #-}

data Stream a = a :> Stream a
     deriving (Foldable)

instance Functor Stream where
    fmap f (x:>xs) = f x :> fmap f xs
```

There are other extensions for example to make it an instance of `Traversable`, `Generic`, `Lift`, etc.

Comment: @ Willem Van Onsem But if I took out ``deriving (Functor, Foldable)`` I could write the instances for them manually? If so, how come my attempt (commented out in the code above) to write the instance for Stream didn't work?

Comment: @user65526: because `Functor` provides the `fmap` function, you did not write `fmap f (x :> xs) = ...`, but `f (x :> xs) = ...`.

Comment: @ Willem Van Onsem Ah yes! Thanks :)

Comment: `DeriveTraversable` implies both `DeriveFunctor` and `DeriveFoldable`, so it's a nice one-stop shop.

Comment: @user65526 It's worth noting that the compiler told you what to do to fix it in the error message.  I realize you didn't have the context necessary to understand it yet in this case, but keep that in mind in the future.  The compiler messages are often really good.

Comment: @Carl "You need DeriveFoldable to derive an instance for this class" is badly written IMO. "You need the language extension DeriveFoldable so that Stream's Foldable instance could be derived automatically" would be a bit better.